# The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect while starting Task Manager or any program from System32 in Win10

Tags: windows-10

I am facing a problem while starting any program from the System32 folder, like Task Manager or Advance System Settings. Every time I get this error:

> The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect while starting Task Manager

I am using Windows 10. Please refer the screenshot link:

[image: Error Screenshot here]

Comment: any of the following chars in your volumelabel? `\\ \\ / [ ] : | < > + ; = . ? "` if so, rename your volume

Comment: Hi @SimonS I have added the screenshot.

Comment: if you open diskmanagement (right click on Windows-start-icon > diskmanagement) on the left hand side, is there any strange name with one of the chars in it i mentioned in my first comment? If so, rename it http://www.howtogeek.com/206197/how-to-use-label-to-rename-drives-from-the-windows-command-prompt/

Comment: The thing is It is giving same error for opening disk management also.

Comment: hmm... also when you open cmd? with cmd you can use `diskpart` to see volumes etc. http://www.inteligentcomp.com/2013/01/disk-management-in-command-prompt.html

Comment: Is it related with System variables? Because I also tried starting program manually from System32 folder and it still gives above error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with everything possible option, it was working fine through safe mode but not from normal login. I ended up with restoring my OS to restore point. I referred this link: http://www.howtogeek.com/222532/how-to-repair-corrupted-windows-system-files-with-the-sfc-and-dism-commands/ and it solved my problem.